# jQuery: looking for image slider plugin

Tags: jquery, image, plugins, slider

i'm looking for a simple image slider content with the following features:

- slide several images from right to left with pause (the slider should stop and display the centered image for a second)
- endless looping (the last image should be followed by the first image again)

any recommendations?

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I got sick of image sliders because the are not really customizable. That is why I started using: [jshowoff](http://ekallevig.com/jshowoff/) this is not an images slider but a html slider. You have full control over the styling.

I really loved it for this. Since you want to make the image slider your own.

The demos are on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [jCarousel](http://sorgalla.com/jcarousel/). I've used it before to stunning effect... Very customizable as well. :)

Answer (score 1):

I use jQueryCycle a lot : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/

It has a lot of options but it's also got a 'lite' version to it that does all you want and it's only 3kb : http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/lite